How to get user password from Strapi?
I just don`t know how to fetch that user password in return, so i can make my bcrypt.compare logic on Login Form.
For registration i am used next logic and endpoint:

/api/auth/local/register

I`ve tried like:

/auth/login + populates + populate deep plugin
/api/users/me - which is not returning that password field for security i guess

I guess i need to modify somehow the controllers, and make custom endpoint to take that data from Strapi, but i wasnt find any info related to that, and i wasnt doing that at all.
Wasnt managed to find that info too, cause everybody seems like want to change they password, and i dont kinda need to change it, i just want that hash back, so i can compare it, thats all.
It seems i will be forced to create controller in Strapi, which i can call to validate user password (pass user - he find him - check - response). Because returning password to front in security issue i guess. But then the question, how to create that controller?
If you have any suggestions how i can get that password for my logic - i will be glad to see that.
"@strapi/strapi": "^4.21.1",
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { z } from 'zod'
import isEmail from 'validator/lib/isEmail'
import { comparePassword } from '@/utils/password-compare'
import { Codes } from '@/constants/code-errors'

export async function POST(request) {
  try {
    const { email, password } = await request.json()
    const saltRounds = 10;
    // http://localhost:8080/api/auth/local
    // const response = await fetchBackendAPI({
    //     resource: '/api/admin/login',
    //     method: 'POST',
    //     fields: nonEmptyFields
    //   })

    const emailCheck = z.string().refine(isEmail)

    if (!emailCheck.safeParse(email).success) {
      return NextResponse.json({ message: "Email is incorrect." }, { status: 404 });
    }

    const hashResult = await comparePassword(password, saltRounds)

    if (hashResult !== false) {
      // Save hashed password
    } else {
      // Error handling
    }

    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT}/api/auth/local`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        identifier: email,
        password: hashResult,
      })
    })

    if (response.ok) {
      console.log("User was logged")
      const newUser = await response.json();
      return NextResponse.json({ newUser }, { status: 200 });
    } else {
      console.log("Response is not ok")
      return NextResponse.json({
        code: response.status,
        message: response.statusText
      }, { status: response.status })
    }

  } catch (err) {
    return NextResponse.json({
      code: Codes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.code,
      err: Codes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.message
    }, { status: 500 })
  }
}

UPDATE:
Since i was trying so hard with browsing all info related to my topics, i find official vid on YT like, how to do controllers, this is what i created
    module.exports = {
  routes: [
    {
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/custom',
      handler: 'todo.customAction',
      config: {
        auth: false
      }
    }
  ]
}

    use strict';
    
    /**
     * todo controller
     */
    
    const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;
    
    modul

e.exports = createCoreController('api::todo.todo', ({ strapi }) => ({
  async customAction (ctx) {
    try {
      const user = await strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').findOne({ username: 'Magister4'})
    } catch (err) {
      ctx.body = err
    }
  }
}))

And this is kinda worked, but i wasn`t able to find, return, or change password. It seems todo.todo have no access to main users-permissions stuff.

I don't understand what you are trying to do?
Are you trying to re-create a reset password feature?
Because Strapi has that build in

To generate a new controller in a new API, you can just run "yarn strapi generate" in your Strapi project.
Then just uncomment the route and controller.
Then use that line to get the user data
await strapi.db.query('plugin::users-permissions.user').findOne({
  where: { email: email }
})

Set the new route Public to be able to access it without being authorized.
Here is the process in a video I made for you:
https://www.loom.com/share/cf60dafff14840c886c6d222530f557b

Great one. Wasn`t noticed, sorry for my brain, it is bad so far :D
But actually i solved it in another way, seems like Strapi removed hashPassword from actuall methods, they still use it underhood.
Like, when you creating password - it is already Hashed by Strapi side, so we dont actually need to bother with that, and then - i dont need password to hashCompare, cause Strapi also doing this.
So i just install basic Auth, and it is working. But youre solution is what i was looking about.
And additional thx for loom, thx for you time, and explanation!

hey @AndreyShaposhnikov can you tell the method you used, i'm also stuck with the same situation here

@ShubhamSinghvi hey, just watch the video that STRAPI co-finder does above. This is litteraly 1 answer here, you cant miss that. It is what you need to get a password.
I wasnt solving that far, because i realised, that i DONT need PASSWORD to compare with hash stuff, because Strapi is checking it ITSELF when you try to LOGIN IN. But if you NEED a PASSWORD for something else - watch a loom above.

@AndreyShaposhnikov yeah thanks for that I saw the video 2...3 times, I got errors, then I realized my problem was not such, after I discovered the google providers section and after many url mismatches ... I finally ended doing the google login and custom user login  :)
